# Need to restart loop

Tags: python, loops

Still a NOOB in Python. Get stuck many times.
Script runs 3 sequencies, one after the other, each for 20 seconds.
Each sequence has a while loop. and a time out statement.
Then it starts the next loop, and so on till the end of end of the 
3rd loop. Then it quits. I would like to start again from the top.
I probably have too many while loops.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Import required libraries
import time
# More setup

# Choose a matrix to use
mat = mat1
t_end = time.time() + 20
#Start loop
while time.time() < t_end:
  # code
  # loop timeout

# 2 more loops follow just like first one, except matrix becomes
mat = mat2
mat = mat3
```

Comment: If your manipulations of `mat2` and `mat3` are identical to that of `mat` then start learning about functions.

Comment: If the three loops are alike, you shouldn't repeat yourself but wrap them in a common function that takes mat1, mat2 or mat3 as argument. Then you can just do myfunction(mat2) and it will be easier to structure your program. Google "function".

Answer (score 0):

As others have already commented, you should do any repetitive tasks within a function.  In Python, functions are defined using the "`def`" keyword.  Using a function, it could be done as follows:

```
import time

#  Replace these dummy assignments with real code
mat1 = "blah"
mat2 = "rhubarb"
mat3 = "custard"

def processMatrix(matrix, seconds=20):
    t_end = time.time() + seconds
    while time.time() < t_end:
        pass  #  'pass' does nothing - replace with your real code

processMatrix(mat1)
processMatrix(mat2)
processMatrix(mat3)
```

Note that I've also included the time/seconds as a parameter in the function.  This gives you more flexibility, in case you wanted to run for different times for testing or different times for each matrix, etc.  However, I've done it with a default value of `20` so that you don't need to include it in the function call.   If you do want to override the default you could call, eg,

```
processMatrix(mat1, 5)
```

instead of,

```
processMatrix(mat1)
```